# try catch 404 error

Tags: javascript

i have a function drawCountry that tries to read a json file based on the clicked country:

```
    d3.json("../json/"+d.id.toLowerCase()+"/regions.json", function(error, json) {
        if (error) {
            return console.warn(error);
            self.drawMap();
        }
        else {
        self.regionsGroup.selectAll("path")
        .data(json.features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", self.projection)
        .attr("id", function(d) {
            return d.properties.name;
        })
        .classed("country", true)
        .attr("class", "country")
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {
            d3.select(this)
            .style("fill", "#6C0")
            .append("svg:title")
            .text(d.properties.name);
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            d3.select(this)
            .style("fill", "#000000");
        })
        .on("click", function(d) {
            console.log('clicked on country')
        });
        }
    });
```

i am not able to see how to load the self.drawMap(); when there is an error?

Answer (score 0):

```
return console.warn(error);  <-- exits out of the function
self.drawMap();  <--never gets called because of the return
```

switch the lines

```
self.drawMap(); 
return console.warn(error);
```